# Raspberry Pi to sync lights to audio input from PC

Tags: raspbian, hardware, audio, led, software-recommendation

Is it possible to make the Raspberry Pi sync lights to sound coming from PC. I would use an usb soundcard for a sound input and AUX audio cable.

I'm running [lightshowpi](http://lightshowpi.org/) which works fine, but it is only capable of syncing lights to a single sound file I provide and not an "endless" audio stream.

I want to sync outgoing sound from Windows PC to lights using the Raspberry Pi, and I don't know if it's possible at all or if I need something else to get this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is already possible with Lightshow Pi. All you have to do is set up your usb audiocard and change the mode of Lighshow Pi to audio-in. Then start the script.

Here's the guide on Lightshow Pi: http://lightshowpi.org/usb-audio-in-support/